# How do I write this JQuery function in plain JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

can you please help me to write this function in plain JavaScript in the most efficient way.

```
//Selects all elements matched by <input> that have a name value 
//exactly equal to myname.
$("input[@name=myname]")
```

Comment: There isn't really an "efficient" way to do this in Javascript other than using the exact same method jQuery is using.  jQuery has done a lot of work on making these selectors extremely efficient.  Is there a reason you can't use jQuery, or is this just an academic exercise?

Comment: No it's not an academic exercise, I'm using JavaScript in my program, and to evaluate JQuery every time I load the page is not good at all..

Comment: Ok? But a lot of existing web sites do that - successfully ;) Even stackoverflow.

Comment: Most (read:every) modern browser caches javascript, so it will not "load" jQuery every time you load the page.

Comment: Especially if you load it from google, like many sites do. Just look at the source of stackoverflow. Think about it, who doesn't have Google in his or her browser's cache - maybe 0.2% of the whole internet?

Comment: To be more clear, it's kinda web crawler that handles lot of requests every second.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var els = document.getElementsByTagName("input"),
    arr = [];

for (var i = 0, l = els.length; i < l; i++) {
    if (els.name === "myname") {
        arr.push(els);
    }
}

console.log(arr);
```

Or for modern browsers:

```
var arr = document.querySelectorAll("input[name='myname']");
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Great thank you very much! the second approach looks very nice and clean

Comment: @Vor However it is [not supported by IE < 8](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll#Browser_compatibility).

Comment: That's fine, as long as webkit support it =)

Answer (score 4):

Is this what you are looking for:

```
document.getElementsByName("myname");
```

Comment: No, it's not, It's just an example, I wouldn't use 'name' in real program

Answer (score 3):

Assuming each element in the form has a unique name, this method is the fastest:

```
var element = document.MyForm.getElementsByName('myname')[0];
```

`document.querySelectorAll()` may be faster if `name` is shared by elements of different tags, but [support is limited](http://caniuse.com/queryselector) .

Comment: Sorry, If my question is not clear enough, but 'name' was just an example